# Como tener dos navigation drawer y mostrarlos de acuerdo a algun parametro

Tags: android-studio, navigationview

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto en android studio y tengo dos navigation drawer, lo que quiero hacer es que al iniciar sesion como cliente me muestre el primer navigation y si inicio sesion como empleado que me muestre el otro navigation. He investigado y lo unico q pude hacer es que se muestre uno en la izquierda y el otro se muestre en la derecha.  No se como hacer que solo se muestre uno dependiendo de si es cliente o si es empleado.

[image: activity main.xml]
[image: Main activity]

[[image: Main activity[3]]

Comment: Prueba de ver si el navigationdrawer se puede cargar un fragment dentro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se hace con un `if/else`.

Primero en tu xml solo deja un widget.NavigationView con id/nav_view
y de allí elimina app:menu ...

En java harás la selección del drawer menu:

```
 String vista="";             // obtienes el string para cliente/empleado
 navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);   // la vista del menu drawer
 if("cliente".equals(vista)){
   //navigationView.getMenu().clear();      //elimina anterior menu drawer
   navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer); //carga el menu drawer
 }else                                  // en caso de "empleado"
   //navigationView.getMenu().clear(); 
   navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_secondary_drawer); 
 }
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Declaras el navigation view y el String vista al inicio de la clase, antes de onCreate:

```
 NavigationView navigationView;
 String vista="";
```

Comment: Wow gracias carnal busque de todo y nunca encontre ese metodo inflateMenu

Comment: si te sirvio marcala como respuesta