# ¿Cómo editar editar los componentes que están en un NavigationView desde java?

Tags: android

Quise editar el texto de un TextView y cambiar la imagen de un ImageView los cuales se encuentran el Header del NavigationView, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Este es el xml de mi header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/navigationHeader">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageUser"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/baseline_face_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameuser"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageUser"
        android:text="Manuel Del Villar"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userrole"
        android:layout_width="229dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameuser"
        android:layout_marginStart="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageUser"
        android:text="Administrador"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

La parte de mi navigation view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Y este es el código con el que intenté cambiar los datos en tiempo de ejecución, está de la misma forma que siempre se cambian los datos en un layout.

```
username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameuser);
userrole  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userrole);

username.setText(CurrentSession.CURREN_NAME_USER);
userrole.setText(CurrentSession.CURRENT_ROLE_USER);
```

Comment: Es posible que el error se encuentre en el manifest revisalo o agregalo a la pregunta.

Comment: Necesitas incluir más conexto sobre el problema. Donde está este código? Es en el onCreate() del activity o en onCreateView() de un fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Aquí hay una respuesta para mostrar uno u otro nav drawer menu: [Como tener dos navigation drawer y mostrarlos de acuerdo a algun parametro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/208075/como-tener-dos-navigation-drawer-y-mostrarlos-de-acuerdo-a-algun-parametro/208403#208403)

Obienes el textView y el ImageView del header de esta forma:

```
    View nav_header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.navigation_header, null);
    ((TextView)  nav_header.findViewById(R.id.nameuser)).setText(CurrentSession.CURREN_NAME_USER);
    ((ImageView) nav_header.findViewById(R.id.imageUser)).setImageResource(R.drawable.TU_IMAGEN);
```

Agregale un id al NavigationView, por ejemplo nav_view.
Obtienes ese id del navigationView, eliminas vista anterior, inflas el drawer menu y le asignas el header:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.getMenu().clear();
 navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer); 
 navigationView.addHeaderView(nav_header);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Por último en tu xml del NavigationView elimina app:menu y app:header:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start">

  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```